# Toopher API: What does the message "No pending pairing requests with specified pairing_phrase" mean?

Tags: ruby, api, toopher

What does the error message, `Not Found: No pending pairing requests with specified pairing_phrase` mean?

I followed the Docs from here: https://dev.toopher.com/docs/

And used the Ruby API from here: https://github.com/toopher/toopher-ruby

When I run the demo I receive the following output:

```
{
  "error_message" => 
      "Not Found: No pending pairing requests with specified pairing_phrase",
  "error_code" =>
      404
}
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is received in one of three conditions:

1. The pairing phrase entered was never created by a user of the Toopher mobile app
2. The pairing phrase entered was too old (pairing phrases are short lived and expire relatively quickly).
3. The pairing phrase entered was already used (pairing phrases can only be used once).

Given this set of causes I'd suggest checking to make sure the pairing phrase you're entering didn't have any typos, wasn't generated more than 10 minutes prior to entering it, and was not already used.

If it's none of these then please report the bug to [dev@toopher.com](http://mailto%3adev@toopher.com).

Hope this helps.  Thanks for the question!